# Default font for Rich Text field

Tags: richtextbox, xpages

In my xpages application, I have one comments field that is a rich text field.  My users would like the default font to be Courier New.  Yes, they can click the drop down and select Courier New, but they would like to be able to just start typing.    I tried setting the style on the rich text control, but that didn't work.  In the theme somehow maybe?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

in theory (to be honest, I've never done it myself) this can be done through the rt editor's configuration. Xpages by default come with CKEditor which has its own JS API; you can find the documentation here:

[CKEditor API](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/index.html)

The relevant config.js is stored server-side at this location:

[domino-data]/domino/html/ckeditor/config.js

Comment: fantastic.  thanks - that did it.  Looks like font_defaultLabel is what i need.