# Set default font/text size in RTF Control

Tags: ckeditor, xpages, xpinc

I found this answer [Default font for Rich Text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040875/default-font-for-rich-text-field) but it doesn't help me. I need to be able to set it in the application as this is an XPiNC (Xpages in Notes Client for those reading this in the CKEditor forum) app and I have no control over what is on the system beyond IBM Notes 8.5.3FP4. Because the config.js is server side for the CKEditor, I need to do this in the code or css somehow.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You can use an XSP.addOnLoad to alter any loaded value. This applies to CK editor values too

Answer (score 3):

Add the following script block to your XPage. It will set the initial font and text size in CKEditor field.

```
<xp:scriptBlock
    id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value>
        <![CDATA[XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
                    try{
                        CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
                            if (ev.editor.getData() === "") {
                                ev.editor.setData('<span style="font-family: Comic Sans MS, cursive; font-size:36px;">&shy;</span>');
                            }
                        });
                    }catch(e){
                        console.log(e);
                    }
    })]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

The trick is to set an initial value to field with a style when field is empty.

(Unfortunately, all attempts to set `config.font_defaultLabel` and `config.fontSize_defaultLabel` **don't** work like:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
        config.font_defaultLabel = 'Comic Sans MS, cursive';
        config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '36px';
};
```

)

Comment: Well that didn't work. It didn't affect the RTFs at all. Back to the drawing board. This should have been built in from the beginning. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, it worked for me though. I tested it with Demonstration Application for XPages http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/release.xsp?databaseName=CN=NotesOSS2/O=NotesOSS!!Projects%5Cpmt.nsf&documentId=6A7183975BEB85A786257AFB00700639&action=openDocument in XPage ctrlsCoreRichText in XPiNC version 8.5.3 FP3

Comment: Just tested it with a new XPage with one RTF connected to a Domino Document data source Body field and the embedded script block above. It works: when you click in RTF font and text size are set to values from script block. Does it work for you in a new XPage?

Comment: Just for clarification: this is a solution to set RTF's default font and text size when you start typing in an empty RTF. It doesn't effect existing text in RTFs. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes I am looking for a way to set a default font/size (Arial/16) to all 6 RTFs on a page.

Comment: Knut, can I modify the script to work for an individual RTF control if I have more than 1 on my page?

Answer (score 1):

Knut's solutions works great except you have to use `&#8203;` instead of `&shy;` as you lose the font styling when clicking into the field and start typing.

Comment: Good to know. `&#8203;` is more flexible than `&shy;` although the latter worked for me too. Thanks Oliver.

Comment: Just tested it for Domino 8.5.3 and 9.0.1.3: `&#8203;` does work for browsers Chrome41, Firefox35, and IE11 and `&shy;` does work for Firefox35, and IE11 but not for Chrome41.